# Find the distance of each pair between two vectors

Tags: python, scipy

I have two vectors, let's say `x=[2,4,6,7]` and `y=[2,6,7,8]` and I want to find the euclidean distance, or any other implemented distance (from scipy for example), between each corresponding pair. That will be
`dist=[0, 2, 1, 1]`.

When I try

```
dist = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(x,y, metric='sqeuclidean')
```

or

```
dist = [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(x,y, metric='sqeuclidean') for x,y in zip(x,y)]
```

I get

```
ValueError: XA must be a 2-dimensional array.
```

How am I supposed to calculate dist and why do I have to reshape data for that purpose?

Comment: Be careful with the variable names you use inside list comprehensions (`for x, y`). After the comprehension is executed, they remain visible. In your example, those variables are the same as the `x` and `y` vectors you are `zip`ping, so after the comprehension is done, `x` and `y` will be equal to the last values of each vector, not the vectors themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cdist does not compute the list of distances between corresponding pairs, but the matrix of distances between all pairs.

```
np.linalg.norm((np.asarray(x)-np.asarray(y))[:, None], axis=1)
```

Is how id typically write this for the Euclidian distance between n-dimensional points; but if you are only dealing with 1 dimensional points, the absolute difference, as suggested by elpres would be simpler.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` list here as user has provided? I am not sure that would work.

Comment: I am looking for way that will let me apply any implemented distance metric from scipy for example. Actually I need the distance of each value of a 1d vector from a scalar.

Comment: check out the ord kwarg of linalg.norm; it has a lot of options for different norms