# Vectorizing radial basis function's euclidean distance calculation for multidimensional features

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-algebra

I suspect there is probably a SO post that has answered this question, but I have not been able to find it yet, so I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question.

I'm attempting to implement a radial basis function kernel from scratch using Numpy for my own learning purposes. For one-dimensional inputs, the calculation is pretty easy:

```
def kernel(x, y):
    return * np.exp( -0.5 * np.subtract.outer(x, y)**2)
```

The above is from a [blog post on Gaussian Processes](https://blog.dominodatalab.com/fitting-gaussian-process-models-python/).

But I'm trying to extend this to multiple dimensions. I have an implementation that works fine below:

```
x = np.array([[4,3,5], [1,3,9], [0,1,0], [4,3,5]])
distances = []
γ = -.5
for i in x:
    for j in x:
        distances.append(np.exp(γ * np.linalg.norm(i - j) ** 2))
np.array(distances).reshape(len(x),len(x))

[[1.00000000e+00 3.72665317e-06 1.69189792e-10 1.00000000e+00]
 [3.72665317e-06 1.00000000e+00 2.11513104e-19 3.72665317e-06]
 [1.69189792e-10 2.11513104e-19 1.00000000e+00 1.69189792e-10]
 [1.00000000e+00 3.72665317e-06 1.69189792e-10 1.00000000e+00]]
```

I am checking using `sklearn.pairwise.rbf_kernel`

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import rbf_kernel
print(rbf_kernel(x, gamma= .5))

[[1.00000000e+00 3.72665317e-06 1.69189792e-10 1.00000000e+00]
 [3.72665317e-06 1.00000000e+00 2.11513104e-19 3.72665317e-06]
 [1.69189792e-10 2.11513104e-19 1.00000000e+00 1.69189792e-10]
 [1.00000000e+00 3.72665317e-06 1.69189792e-10 1.00000000e+00]]
```

But clearly the double for loops are not the most efficient way of iterating through this. What's the best way to vectorize this operation?

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692720/find-the-distance-of-each-pair-between-two-vectors) provides an efficient way of calculating distances, but does not provide the vectorization I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the following observation to solve the problem:

`||a - b|| ** 2 = ||a|| ** 2 + ||b|| ** 2 - 2 * <a, b>`

In code, it will look as following:

```
x_norm = np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1) ** 2
output = np.exp(- 0.5 * (x_norm.reshape(-1, 1) + x_norm.reshape(1, -1) - 2 * np.dot(x, x.T)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [SciPy's `cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) and then scale those with the exponential values -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

lam = -.5
out = np.exp(lam* cdist(x,x,'sqeuclidean'))
```

We can also [leverage `matrix-mutliplication`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877630/) -

```
def sqcdist_own(x):
    row_sum = (x**2).sum(1) # or np.einsum('ij,ij->i',x,x)
    sqeucdist = row_sum - 2*x.dot(x.T)
    sqeucdist += row_sum[:,None]
    return sqeucdist

out = np.exp(lam* cdist(x,x,'sqeuclidean'))
```

To use these approaches on both `2D` and `1D` cases, reshape `x` to `2D` as a pre-processing step : `X = x.reshape(len(x),-1)` and then use `X` instead as the input into these solutions.